# aws-cdk: I cannot add access permission to existing SQS

Tags: amazon-sqs, aws-cdk

I have a code where I need to grant send messages to an existing sqs queue.

I have this code in the aws-cdk. But this is not working. No access permission get added.

```
const sqsQ = sqs.Queue.fromQueueArn(this, "some-id", "arn:aws:sqs:us-east-2:SOME-ACCOUNT:QUEUE-NAME");
sqsQ.grantSendMessages(new iam.ServicePrincipal("events.amazonaws.com"));
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I don't think it's possible to grant permissions to an existing resource in CDK. Anytime you import a resource into your stack using something like `fromQueueArn` you can think of this as a read-only reference to the resource.

In other words, you can only update resources which are managed by your CDK code.

You have basically 2 options here:

1. Move the original SQS into your CDK managed stack. You can do this using CloudFormation resource import feature (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/resource-import.html)
2. Modify SQS permissions outside CDK in the place where it was originally defined.

Comment: Are buckets special? This documentation is what made me think you can do that. 
Look at https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/latest/docs/aws-s3-readme.html#importing-existing-buckets

Comment: If you're referring to `bucket.grantReadWrite(user)`, then the explanation for why that works is that this operation actually modified user, not the bucket, i.e. it's not modifying bucket resource. It's modifying IAM resource.

Comment: Is this still true?

Answer (score 6):

Try something like this instead

```
    sqsQ.addToResourcePolicy(
      new PolicyStatement({
        effect: Effect.ALLOW,
        principals: [new ServicePrincipal(ServicePrincipals.EVENTS)],
        actions: ["sqs:SendMessage"],
        resources: [sqsQ.queueArn],
        conditions: {
          ArnEquals: {
            "aws:SourceArn": <ruleArn or whatever needs permissions here>,
          },
        },
      })
    );
```

Comment: When you say it did not work how are you checking, are you looking at the permissions on the AWS console and seeing nothing has been added?

Comment: @AnonymousAlias, Yes. Also CDK stack does not show that as a resource change that is going to added

Comment: Ahh hadn't copped you were dealing with an import, this makes sense.